# What really are Maven dependencies?

Tags: eclipse, maven, dependencies

I tried searching google and the forum but I couldn't get to an exact and foremost simple answer. I am still a beginner but I have to do a project in Eclipse about Maven and dependencies and how do I deploy them. My question is really what are dependencies and how do I know what dependencies I have to include for a certain project? I hope the question doesn't sound that stupid but I am a bit confused as to probably every project needs different dependencies but how exactly do we pick which ones do we need? 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maven dependencies are different artifacts and artifact could be of any type, for example jar, war, ear, xml or any other format. Generally speaking Dependencies are the libraries which are required by your project and while developing your project you/developer should know which library he is using, For example if you are building something on Spring Core and your project require Spring Core jar file then you can say that Spring Core is dependency of your project.

Common or Open Source dependencies are already hosted on maven central repository and when you give the correct coordinates of that required dependency in your pom file, maven fetches that dependency for you from the specified repository.

Dependencies have different scopes, for example compile, test etc, it mean that for what purpose you need that dependency for example if a dependency's scope is test then it means you only require it for executing the unit tests.

I hope this has answered your question. For further understand you may read any good book on Maven.

Comment: Have a look at this as well -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26579837/maven-dependency-vs-multimodule/26581358#26581358